# Custom JAVA location for selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, testing, jenkins

I launch selenium tests in Jenkins using a maven-structure project. 
The default java location is 
`/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java`
But I need to run tests with the java from a different location: 
`/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64`
So I set it in Jenkins node configuration in "Inject environment variable":

`Properties Content  - JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jre-1.8.0-openjdk.x86_64`

http://screencast.com/t/oTxdKFOC
and I don't set any additional java home settings in pom file. 
But when I run tests (mvn clean test) I get the following output:

`Java version: 1.8.0_51, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.51-1.b16.6.amzn1.x86_64/jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "3.10.35-43.137.amzn1.x86_64", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"`

And then:

`[selenium] $ /usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=786M -Dgwt.compiler.localWorkers=1`

http://screencast.com/t/jfNMxIV7
So it always starts from `/usr/lib/jvm/java-openjdk/bin/java` whatever I set. (In MAVEN_OPTS there are only `-Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=786M` options set)

How can I make it use custom java 8 location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting it in the Global location - 
Go to Manage Jenkins, Configure System, JDK  - there add a JDK installation to your specific path.

Comment: Great! I finally set it up! Thank you!